# How to insert Batch input into Python

Tags: python, batch-file

I want that my `set /p Input1 =` does something like `py "Python.py" %Input1%` but with multiple inputs. I also want to get the input from that very batch file into a python code. How do I take the input? I normally do it with a single input like `sys.argv()` but that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Take care with spaces in a batch `set` command i.e. `set /p Input=` sets `%Input%` while `set /p Input =` sets `%Input %`. Perhaps why `%Input%` is not working for you as it is undefined.

Comment: Repeat: `set /p Input =` sets `%Input %`. Wrap in previous comment may spoil the space in the inline code.

Comment: Do you mean like `Set /P "Input1= "` followed by `Set "Input1=py "Python.py" %Input1%"`?

Answer (score 0):

**sys.argv** returns a list of command line arguments you pass to the program. Like if you run the command as `python demo.py var1 var2 var3` the **sys.argv** will return the list `['demo.py', 'var1', 'var2', 'var3']` just choose the index of whatever you want. Example **sys.argv[0]** will return **'demo.py'**, **sys.argv[1]** will return **'var1'**